# when execute two AsyncTask in same fragment activity my application hanging and still loading

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask, java-threads

I am trying to execute two AsyncTask in the same fragment but when I run my application, my phone freezes and still loading  this my code
when I execute one asynTask every thing is ok

this where it try to execute

```
     @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        Log.w(LOG_TAG,"onActivityCreated------------");

 // First AsyncTask execution called  
    new RecomenddedChaneel().execute();

//Second AsyncTask execution called
    new Loadchannels().execute();

//this is the first asyncTask method

     public class RecomenddedChaneel extends  AsyncTask<String, Void, List<Video>> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading channel list. Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }
     @Override
        protected List<Video> doInBackground(String... urls) {
            channelForCategory= new ArrayList<Video>();
            channelForCategory.clear();

            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("uky", uk));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("per_page","10"));
            JSONObject json = JsonFromHttp.makeHttpRequest(url+"getrecommended_top","POST", params);

            try {
                products=json.getJSONArray("products");
                channelForCategory.clear();
                listchD.clear();
                String imageViewch =null;
                for(int i =0; i <products.length();i++){
                    JSONObject details = products.getJSONObject(i);
                    String pid =details.getString("pid");
                    String cid=details.getString("cid");
                    String name= details.getString("name");
                    Log.v("",name);
                    if(details.has("imageViewch")){
                        imageViewch = details.getString("imageViewch");}
                    String image_url_path= imageurl+imageViewch;
                    channelForCategory.add(new Video(pid,cid,name,image_url_path));
                    listchD.add(new Video(name,pid));
                    Log.w(LOG_TAG,"pid*************all************"+pid);
                    Log.w(LOG_TAG,"cid*********all**********"+cid);
                    Log.w(LOG_TAG,"name********all**********"+name);
                    Log.w(LOG_TAG,"imagelink*********all***********"+imageViewch);

                }

            } catch (JSONException e){
                Log.e("SetHttp", "Problem parsing News JSON results", e);
            }
            return null;
            // return videos;
     @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<Video> video) {
            pDialog.dismiss();          

     ChannelRecycleViewAdapter channelRecycleViewAdapter1
                    = new ChannelRecycleViewAdapter(getActivity(), channelForCategory, new ChannelRecycleViewAdapter.ListItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onListItemClick(int clickedItemIndex) {
                    Video videoch= channelForCategory.get(clickedItemIndex);
                    String  urlch=videoch.getmpid();
                    Intent inturl= new Intent(getActivity(),VideoPlayer.class);
                    inturl.putExtra("urlch",urlch);
                    inturl.putExtra("list_video_name", (Serializable) listchD);
                    startActivity(inturl);

                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                            urlch, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            });
            recyclerView1.setAdapter(channelRecycleViewAdapter1);
```

and the second asynctask is the copy of the first asynctask.
I don't know why app hanging and still loading.

Comment: Single aynctask is simple when come to multiple & more aync task at same time you have to use THREAD_POOL_EXECUTER. Depending on the sdk version you have to customize it. Have a look at this http://blogs.innovationm.com/multiple-asynctask-in-android/

Comment: @MohamedMohaideenAH
thank you it done

Comment: `channelForCategory`. That should be a local variable of your async task. It looks as if it is global. If you use other global variables then make them local. You do not have to use tread pool executer. That has nothing to do with your problem.

Comment: no i change it to be local  but nothing happen 
but when hide Progress dialog  in one of asynTask  it done .